Work done in a system of masses
Let's say we have this system:

Why is the work
$$W_{tot} = mgh - F_f h$$
where $F_fh$ is the work done by friction?
I don't know why this happens. My guess would be to consider both blocks as one and that the $mgh$ is in the direction of the movement and the friction is in the opposite direction of both blocks. Am I correct?

@hft my teacher gave me that equations I don't what is it

@hft are you sure? it is on a book solver not teacher but book

I'm sure that work and force have different dimension, yes.

@hft I see I forgot to add the h to the friction which is the work done by gravity minus the work done by friction why is that?

@hft book says that is the total  I dont understand why

sir are you still here?

Forces do work, and this doesn't depend on how we define the system. So yes, you can consider the total work done on both blocks, treating the system to be both blocks. And yes, the weight force acts along a displacement $h$ and the friction force acts against the displacement $h$. Since both the weight force and friction are constant, we can just multiply each force by the displacement (along with the appropriate sign) to give the total work.
The tension force also does work, but if the tension force on each block is equal, then the work tension does on one block is exactly cancelled by the work done by tension on the other block, and so the work done by tension will not be included in the total work expression.
